# Unparseable date exception in java

Tags: java, android, datetime, date

These lines of codes

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy"); 

     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_EVENT_ID, appointment.mEventId);
        try {
            values.put(COL_START_DATE, String.valueOf(formatter.parse(appointment.mStartDate.toString())));
            values.put(COL_END_DATE, String.valueOf(formatter.parse(appointment.mEndDate.toString())));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

causees this exception

```
10-15 11:44:38.150: WARN/System.err(3861): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Jan 10 00:10:00 GMT+02:00 2011"
```

what is the possible solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format is completely wrong. Not only are you using `mm` (which means minutes) when you probably meant `MM`, but this:

```
Mon Jan 10 00:10:00 GMT+02:00 2011
```

is clearly *not* in the format

```
dd/MM/yy
```

You probably want something like

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

EDIT: That works for me in desktop Java:

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String value = "Mon Jan 10 00:10:00 GMT+02:00 2011";
        String pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        System.out.println(format.parse(value));
    }
}
```

You may want to set the culture of the `SimpleDateFormat` of course.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Mon Jan 10 00:10:00 GMT+02:00 2011";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d H:m:s OOOO uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gYrppW)

**Notes:**

1. `m` specifies *minute-of-hour* whereas `M` specifies *month-of-year*. You have wrongly used the former.
2. The pattern used with the parser (`DateTimeFormatter` or `SimpleDateFormat`) should match the input date-time string. Your pattern, `dd/mm/yy` is off by far.
3. [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>